# TreeView's contextmenu appears on the topnode instead of TreeViewItem's

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I've got a problem I couldn't find solution for. Here is my TreeView's XAML:

```
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource TreeViewContextMenu}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
```

And I've also got this style in my `ContentControl.Resources`:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemContextMenu}" />
    </Style>
```

When I rightclick any item apart from the very first one, the `TreeViewItemContextMenu` appears, just as intended.
But the issue is when I rightclick the topnode, the `TreeViewContextMenu` appears instead.
I tried to do without the `TreeViewContextMenu` at all, but then the topnode had no `ContextMenu` either.

I would be very glad to know, what and where I missed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you try rightclick on title of topnode? I think your topnode title short. I see you use StackPanel. Stackpanel stretch TreeViewItem and you maybe click outside stackpanel.

Comment: I tried rightclicking the `TextBlock` and the `Image` with the same result: if I rightclick the topnode, the `ContextMenu` that appears is wrong, but if I rightclick any other node (doesn't matter if i rightckick `Image` or `TextBlock`), the result is right. That's really weird to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm trying using your `xaml code`. This is works.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="TreeViewItemContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Item Menu"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu x:Key="TreeViewContextMenu">
            <MenuItem Header="Tree Menu"/>
        </ContextMenu>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource TreeViewItemContextMenu}" />
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Parents}" ContextMenu="{StaticResource TreeViewContextMenu}">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Image}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In code

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            Parents = new ObservableCollection<MyTreeItem>();
            var children=new ObservableCollection<MyTreeItem>();
            children.Add(new MyTreeItem(){ Name="child1"});
            children.Add(new MyTreeItem(){ Name="child2"});
            Parents.Add(new MyTreeItem() { Name = "Parent Node", Children = children });

            this.DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<MyTreeItem> Parents { get; set; }

    }

    public class MyTreeItem {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ObservableCollection<MyTreeItem> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

When i click on the top node and child node, Context menu is same

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake while writing the question. Don't know if it's necessary, but the entire thing is actually not `Window` but `ContentControl` that is placed elsewhere. I've edited the question.

Comment: Well... what I've done is I created new item with the same code as it was before. And it works! Kind of magic or something, don't know. Anyway, thank you for the answer, it led me to the result I needed.